# MYSQL, PHP: INSERT INTO table2 from table 1 only if the project ID is not in second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:leads and projects. Only leads is manually filled. 
When a lead record is assigned as a project, it should be inserted into the projects table.

I need to select the columns `project_number`,`title`,`segment`,`type_project`, `source` from the table `management_leads` and Insert into the table `management_projects` in the columns  `project_number`,`title`,`segment`,`type_project`, `source` ONLY if `management_leads.project_number` not exists in the `management_projects.project_number` column.

This is what I have so far but isn't working:

```
$query="INSERT INTO p_management_projects (project_number,title, segment, type_project) 
SELECT  project_number, title, segment, type_project FROM `p_management_leads` AS leads, 
`p_management_projects` AS projects WHERE leads.status='Project' AND
leads.transfered='No' AND leads.projects_number != projects.projects_number";
```

Comment: Why are you replicating that data? Wouldn't a simple reference be enough? Do you need to keep the information in the `p_management_projects` table when a record is dropped from `p_management_leads` one?

Comment: It's for a financial system. The data will be almost the same but will be managed and tracked in different ways.

Comment: Still I don't get why you need to copy the same data if a record *must* have a corrispondence in the first table in order to exists in the second one (see my previous comment). You could store different information in different tables for different uses, but keep the general information about a project in separated table, without making it redundant. I don't know about your db schema, but that's generally a good idea. What if tomorow you'll need to add some kind of `p_abandoned_projects` table?

Comment: In case of abandoned_projects I would just asign a new column to the projects table (ex: active/abandoned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
insert into management_projects (project_number, title, segment, type_project, source)
  select l.project_number, l.title, l.segment, l.type_project, l.source
    from management_leads l
      left join management_projects mp
        on l.project_number = mp.project_number
  where mp.project_number is null;
```

We insert from the `management_leads` table, `left joined` to the `management_projects` table, but only where the `management_projects` values are null - meaning there was no match on `project_number`.

An alternate method would use `where not exists`, rather than the left join:

```
 insert into management_projects (project_number, title, segment, type_project, source)
      select project_number, title, segment, type_project, source
        from management_leads l
        where not exists
          (select 1 
             from management_projects 
             where project_number = l.project_number)
```

And one last alternative would be to enforce a `unique constraint` on management_projects.project_number, and use `insert ignore`

Comment: Many thanks @pala_ The alternate method is doing de job. Cheers!

Comment: @PJ_ no problems. interested to hear how the first one failed if you can be bothered

Comment: Sure, I got ambiguous column error (project_number)

Comment: @PJ_ thanks. i forgot to include the table specifier. it's fixed now so both forms should work